# Assign unique ID if one value is duplicated in at least one of three columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns. There are many missing values on these columns. I would like to create a new unique ID column that gives the same id for each row, which has at least one identical value in one of the three  columns.

The data frame looks like that

```
df=data.frame(id1=c(5,5,NA,NA,NA,5,4,NA,NA),
              id2=c(NA,58,58,58,NA,58,NA,66,66),
              id3=c(NA,NA,NA,581,581,581,NA,669,NA))
df
  id1 id2 id3
1   5  NA  NA
2   5  58  NA
3  NA  58  NA
4  NA  58 581
5  NA  NA 581
6   5  58 581
7   4  NA  NA
8  NA  66 669
9  NA  66  NA
```

The new column should look like that

```
df=data.frame(id1=c(5,5,NA,NA,NA,5,4,NA,NA),
              id2=c(NA,58,58,58,NA,58,NA,66,66),
              id3=c(NA,NA,NA,581,581,581,NA,669,NA),
              ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3))
  id1 id2 id3 ID
1   5  NA  NA  1
2   5  58  NA  1
3  NA  58  NA  1
4  NA  58 581  1
5  NA  NA 581  1
6   5  58 581  1
7   4  NA  NA  2
8  NA  66 669  3
9  NA  66  NA  3
```

Comment: if '58' for id2 is at row 9, then what would be its id

Comment: In your example data this looks very straightforward, each `ID` corresponds to a single value in each of `id1`, `id2`, and `id3`. Is that actually the case? If there was another row that had `5` for `id1` and `66` for `id2`, would you want to collapse all the `ID` 3 and 1 into a single group?

Comment: @akrun: If row 9 would have an id2 of '58', the ID should be 1.

Comment: @Gregor: It is actually the case that each ID correspnds to a single value in each of id1, id2 and id3. It is not possible that a row has a 5 for id1 and a 66 for id2.

Answer (score 0):

Given your response to @Gregor 's question, here is a somewhat generalizable solution:

```
ID1.criteria <- c(5,58,581)
ID2.criteria <- c(4)
ID3.criteria <- c(66,669)
ID <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (any(df[i,] %in% ID1.criteria)) {
    ID[i] <- 1
  } else {
    if (any(df[i,] %in% ID2.criteria)) {
      ID[i] <- 2
    } else {
      if (any(df[i,] %in% ID3.criteria)) {
        ID[i] <- 3
      } else {
        ID[i] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
}
df$ID <- ID
df
  id1 id2 id3 ID
1   5  NA  NA  1
2   5  58  NA  1
3  NA  58  NA  1
4  NA  58 581  1
5  NA  NA 581  1
6   5  58 581  1
7   4  NA  NA  2
8  NA  66 669  3
9  NA  66  NA  3
```

If needed, you can set the criteria to be whatever you need, given that a finite set of id1, id2, and id3 correspond to the same of ID numbers, independent of the order they come in, and that they are never present on the same row.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. However, the problem is that my data frame is very big. I have more than 2000 pairs of unique IDs. Thus, I would have to write more than 2000 lines of code to specify each IDX.criteria?

Comment: Right, I believe so. As per your response to @akrun, if a new line that has any number that corresponds to `ID 1` gets categorized as `1`, such as a `58` on row 9, or 10, or so on, then the order and sequence is rendered meaningless. The only criteria for categorizing `ID` is the unique collection of specific numbers that appear in columns 1 through 3. Unless I am understanding incorrectly, there is no systematic pattern.